# Pass parameter to DAX query

Tags: reporting-services, dax

I am using a DAX query to establish a dataset for a reporting services report. I want to use parameters so the users can filter for date and position, but I have no idea how I should pass these variables to my DAX expression.

This is my DAX query to retrieve the dataset:

```
EVALUATE
(
ADDCOLUMNS (  
    'Case',
    "Casenumber", RELATED( 'Casedetails'[Casenumber]),
    "Casetitle", RELATED('Casedetails'[Casetitle]),
    "Date", RELATED ( 'Casedates'[Shortdate]),
    "Caselink", RELATED ( 'Casedetails'[Caselink]),
    "Place", RELATED('Geography'[Place])
    )
)
```

How can I establish a filter based on the parameters @Date and @Place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your DAX query to use the calculatetable function. This function accepts a second parameter that filters the first parameter. See sample code below:

```
EVALUATE
(
    CALCULATETABLE
    (
        ADDCOLUMNS (  
            'Case',
            "Casenumber", RELATED( 'Casedetails'[Casenumber]),
            "Casetitle", RELATED('Casedetails'[Casetitle]),
            "Date", RELATED ( 'Casedates'[Shortdate]),
            "Caselink", RELATED ( 'Casedetails'[Caselink]),
            "Place", RELATED('Geography'[Place])
            ),
//insert filters here
        'Casedates'[Shortdate] = @Date,
        'Geography'[Place] = @Place
    )
)
```

You will then need to add the parameter in the query designer as you would normally in SSRS. You also need to add the parameter at a report level globally as you normally would. I assume you already know that you need to use the DMX option in the query designer to execute DAX in SSRS.

Let me know if this works, my DAX is a bit rusty!

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Kalim ! When trying your solution with dummy variables I get the following `Query (3,1) Argument '3' in CALCULATETABLE function is required`

Comment: It was most likely an extra comma after your last filter...I got the same error when i had an extra comma. Glad to have helped.